# Как вставить картинку в шаблонизаторе jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно вставить картинку в массив? Желательно чтобы путь был через src или из вариантов только из буфера? Если только из буфера то как?

Код

```
`http://codepen.io/rublev/pen/ZOYvNL`

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Product data to be used in shop and in cart
  var products = {
    'Нью-Йорк' : ['Нью-Йорк', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры 1300гр.", 699, '', 1],
    'Вегитарианская' : ['Вегитарианская', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры 1300гр.", 699, '', 2],  
    'Семушка' : ['Семушка', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры 1300гр.", 699, '', 3],
    'Жульета' : ['Жульета', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры, яйцо 1300гр.", 699, '', 4],
    'Столичная' : ['Столичная', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры 1300гр.", 699, '', 5],
    'Кальционе по-мексикански' : ['Кальционе', "Сыр, шампиньоны,салями, помидоры 1300гр.", 699, '', 6]
  };

  var drinks = {
    'Coca-cola' : ['Coca-cola', "0.33", 69, '', 1],
    'Pepsi' : ['Pepsi', "0.33", 69, '..img/pepsi.png' , 2],
    'Heineken' : ['Heineken', "0.33", 69, '', 3]
  };  

  // Populates shop with items based on template and data in var products

  var $shop = $('.shop');
  var $shopDrinks = $('.shopDrinks');
  var $cart = $('.cart-items');

  for(var item in products) {
    var itemName = products[item][0],
        itemDescription = products[item][1],
        itemPrice = products[item][2],
        itemImg = products[item][3],
        itemId = products[item][4],
        $template = $($('#productTemplate').html());

    $template.find('.main-menu__product-name').text(itemName);
    $template.find('.pizza-structure').text(itemDescription);
    $template.find('.main-menu__cash').text(itemPrice + 'Р');

    $template.data('id', itemId);
    $template.data('name', itemName);
    $template.data('description', itemDescription);
    $template.data('price', itemPrice);
    $template.data('image', itemImg);

    $shop.append($template);

  }

     for(var drink in drinks){
      var drinkName = drinks[drink][0],
          drinkSize = drinks[drink][1],
          drinkPrice = drinks[drink][2],
          drinkImg = drinks[drink][3],
          drinkId = drinks[drink][4],
          $template = $($('#drinkTemplate').html());

    $template.find('.drink-name').text(drinkName);
    $template.find('.drink-price').text(drinkPrice + 'Р');
    $template.find('drink-img', 'src(' + drinkImg + ')');
    $template.find('.drink-size').text(drinkSize);

    $template.data('id', drinkId);
    $template.data('name', drinkName);
    $template.data('price', drinkPrice);
    $template.data('img', drinkImg);
    $template.data('size', drinkSize);

    $shopDrinks.append($template);         

    }

});
```

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно  быть в самом вопросе. Ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Исправил, добавил код.